# Huffman canonical algorithm. Storing the code table

Tags: algorithm, encoding, zip, php-ziparchive

I implement the canonical Huffman algorithm and there are several questions on the theoretical part, namely about storing of information for decoding. As a method, it's proposed to transmit alphabetical characters and lengths of their canonical codes together with encoded data, because for restoring the canonical table, we only need the code lengths.

Example: string "bbbaacd". Canonical codes: b 0 (1 bit) a 10 (2) c 110 (3) d 111 (3) i.e. decoding data: b1a2c3d3. This raises several questions.

1)Is it necessary to transfer this table in one file along with encoded data according to the table (at the end / beginning of the file)? Are there any real examples?

2)If yes, then if there are numbers in the data, how to understand where in our table is the alphabet symbol (number), and where is the number of bits (length)?

3)And finally, how to understand where is the border between the table and the encoded data?

If everything is stored in separate files (which, in my opinion, is simpler and more logical), then the last 2 questions disappear by themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally the code lengths are stored in the same file as the data.  If you set a maximum code length of 16 bits, for example, then the first 128 bytes in your file can be the lengths of the codes for all 256 bytes (4 bits each).

A slightly more sophisticated way would be to Huffman-encode those lengths.  You can use a fixed tree for that... or you can use a dynamic tree and first write out the lengths of the symbols for each length.